# WYSIWYG/TinyMCE: how to prevent inserting <p> tags

Tags: wysiwyg, tinymce

For the homepage of a magento shop I use the following code in the plain text editor:

```
<p>Some text...</p>
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list"
    alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

When I save this, magento switches to the WYSIWYG editor. When I change back to the plain editor, I see that magento has inserted some code:

```
<p>Some text...</p>
<p>{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list"
    alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</p>
```

How can I prevent this `<p>` tag to be inserted. Do I need to remove this editor, or can I use another one?

Comment: you could just disable the WYSIWYG-Editor by default, so magento will not override your changes if you reopen the page/block.

`Admin > System > Configuration > Content Management > WYSIWYG Options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually find disabling it all together is the best way to go. If that's an option you can find the settings here:

```
System > Configuration > Content Management > WYSIWYG Options
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful In Magento 2.1.7 Configuration has moved to Stores section. This is the new link :
`Store > Configuration > Content Management > WYSIWYG Options`